# Issue when handling the "\0" in Sql Server Database via Command Parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

When I am making a query for a data from a MS SQL Server database via C# [.Net 4] Code and adding a parameter to the query with a value of `"\0"`, the datareader is obtained without any exception and when i read the data from the datareader, i get the exception.

For testing purposes i have used the `"\0"` in place of a GUID, is there a way to fix this issue other than at the input end.

Comment: @sehe not sure, it could be a problem casting values after they are returned from the database. That would not be a bug imho.

Comment: @saravanan please give a bit more details. What does the table look like? Please also post the exact query and the parameter types.

Comment: Ok, agreed he needs to show more code. Nevertheless, the issue is before receiving a result, it's about passing (possibly invalid) values into a prepared query command

Comment: @sehe : and for Marnix van Valen.  It was my mistake, actually i get the error when i read the data from the datareader, I had checked until execute reader and left out the reader.Read() call.. anyways.. thanks for your reply

Comment: Actually this string is not returning true when checked with IsNullOrEmpty() and IsNullOrWhiteSpace()..

Comment: @saravanan: why are you surprised? It is not null (object reference) and it is not empty (contains `\0`) and is not whitespace (contains `\0`)...

Comment: Why don't you supply the information people are asking for?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing several flavours of Null (.NET Clr `null` references, Database `NULL` values and ASCII 0 character literals).

If you want to pass an empty string in C# pass

```
string emptyString = String.Empty
```

To pass a null value pass `null`;

```
string nullString = null;
```

However, to pass database `NULL`, pass DBNull

```
dbParam.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)? DBNull.Value : str;
```

See also   **[SqlParameter with Nullable value give error while ExecuteNonQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863374/sqlparameter-with-nullable-value-give-error-while-executenonquery)**

Comment: Pls. Note that i got the ASCII 0 character literals from PEX while testing. Is there any way to filter out the 0 character literals with checks in C#?.

Comment: Of course. Just search for the character (`.IndexOf`), replace it (`.Replace("\0", " ")`) or just compare it (`string.Equals(str, "\0")? DBNull.Value : str`)

Comment: I am now doing as you said, but reporting as wrong value instead of replacing. Thank you for clear explanations.

Comment: If you have worked with Pex and Moles, do give me its use in unit testing. I am currently exploring on these.