# null data time value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hi Im trying to save a null value for a datetime (fechaNac) but i cant do it .is it possible to do it using my generic code in asp?

```
public int add(Cliente dato)
        {
            string cmdText = "insert into clientes values ( @nombre, @apellido,@telefono,@celular,@oldtelefono, @oldcelular, @dni , @fechaNac)";
            Dictionary<string, Object> parametros = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            parametros.Add("@nombre", dato.Nombre);
            parametros.Add("@apellido", dato.Apellido);
            parametros.Add("@telefono", dato.Telefono);
            parametros.Add("@celular", dato.Celular);
            parametros.Add("@oldtelefono", dato.OldTelefono);
            parametros.Add("@oldcelular", dato.OldCelular);
            parametros.Add("@dni", dato.Dni);
            parametros.Add("@fechaNac", dato.FechaNac);
            try
            {
                return this.setData(cmdText, parametros);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("No se pudo insertar el usuario en la base de datos", ex);
            }
        }


        public int setData(string cmdText, Dictionary<string, Object> listaParametros)
    {
        int res;
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn)) {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> parametro in listaParametros) {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametro.Key, parametro.Value);
            }
            Conectar();
            try {
                res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("No se pudo insertar el dato", ex);
            } finally {
                Desconectar();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

thanks in advance for your help!
Yanina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to coalesce it to `DBNull.Value` first.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parametro.Key, parametro.Value ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , it doesnt work, this is the sql exception i got with that code , "The column name or the specified values ​​do not correspond to the definition of the table."

Comment: Sounds like there are other, unrelated problems with the script. Try to resolve these in SSMS first, then come back to the app.
Also, it's good practice to specify the columns you're inserting into - `insert into clientes (columnName1, columnName2, etc) values...`

Comment: I debug the application , the only parameter that assigned null is fechaNac  . I cant find what i am doing wrong

Comment: If fechaNac isnt null then it works fine , in SSMS works fine too

Comment: Please specify the columns explicitly in your `INSERT` statement.  It might also help to add the table schema to the question.

Comment: I think Jon is on the right track. It is likely just that you need to cast the value correctly. See examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13451148/685760) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/863380/685760)

Comment: i specify the columns in the insert statement and it works ... thanks so much